# My cpu doesn't support virtualization technology. Is there a way to test wp apps without it?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, cpu, cpu-architecture, hyper-v

I've got an Intel Pentium CPU B960. Doing some researches I've found out that my cpu can't support virtualization technology, so I can't enable Hyper-V. You certainly know that the abilitation of hyper-v is necessary to run emulators on PCs, (like virtual box for operating systems).. In particular I need to test my wp apps, using visual studio, and my question is.. Is there a way to test wp apps with a cpu like mine?

Sorry for my English, I hope you'll understand. Thanks.

Comment: If you're not using all the features from the later OS versions, you could target Windows Phone 7.1, the emulator that comes with the SDK for that does not require Hyper-V to run.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to debug your app on a windows phone.  The only emulators available require hyper-v